# Как создать контекст рисования глобально в mfc c++?

Tags: c++, mfc, рисование

Рисую график в mfc c++; Чтобы отрисовать линию в MFC нужно создать контекст рисования типа такого:

```
 CClientDC dc1(this); //Создание контекста, this - указатель на окно. 
 dc1.LineTo(X, Y); //Прорисовка линии к точке с координатами X, Y;
```

Мне нужно много методов, которые будут отрисовывать разные сущности. В каждом методе создавать контекст (с системой координат и т.д.) очень не удобно.

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как-нибудь создать контекст рисования глобально?

Я пробовал записать в .h файл

```
CClientDC dc1(this);
```

Пишет, что синтаксическая ошибка и требуется спецификатор типа.

Comment: Передавайте `dc1` в каждый метод для отрисовки.

Comment: Так делал. Мне не понравилось.